# how to display session data in a view CI

Tags: codeigniter

I tried store data in a session using CI in my register function.

```
public function register(){
    $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');    
    $email= $this->input->post('email');
    $dev_info = array('fname'=>$firstname, 'eaddress'=>$email);
    $this->session->set_userdata($dev_info);
}
```

and in my other function verification I want to get the session data and pass to the view

```
public function verification(){
    $data['fname'] = $this->session->userdata('fname');
    $data['eaddress'] = $this->session->userdata('eaddress');
    $this->load->view('index', $data);
}
```

and I want to save its value in input type

in the view

```
<input type="hidden" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $fname?>">
<input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $eaddress?>">
```

but i am having a hard time saving its value in an input everytime I check using view source. Please help!

Comment: Have you loaded your session library?

Answer (score 2):

you can get session variables one by one also

```
$first_name    = $this->session->userdata('fname');
$email_address = $this->session->userdata('eaddress');
```

in view you can use these variables or you can write code for view like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('eaddress'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('fname')?>">
```

Comment: i tried it sir but still failed. i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: what type of error you get? is you load session library?

Comment: nothing. I just dont see the value in my input when I echo it. yes. Actually i successfully save data in a session. when I console.log the the session value in an ajax call.

Comment: print_r($fname) for check you session

Comment: you have set same id for both hidden input fields. id must be unique so first change id's

Comment: it was a typo sorry. but in my view each id has different ids

Answer (score 0):

in controller create session for ur input data

```
$data['fname'] = $this->session->userdata('fname');
$data['eaddress'] = $this->session->userdata('eaddress');
```

in view retrieve the input data from the session by adding the value by set_value

```
<input type="hidden" id="firstname" value="<?php echo set_value('fname'); ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="email" value="<?php echo set_value('eaddress'); ?>">
```

Comment: add some description to it

Comment: what description? i m newbie here

Comment: A description of the code, that why it will solve and issue and how